# I tried to export mails from Lotus to excel tables, but it don't work like I expected

Tags: excel, lotus-notes, lotus, vba

I'm a little be sutck in this thing. The problem is I would like to export my mails to an excel file, this part is work fine but if I want to change the (.nfs) file to another user Lotus Notes file and run this script bleow, I'll get my mails and not the other Lotus user mails. So it dosen't matter what I write in to the path, it's alwasy run and exported with my mails ! If I just leave the path empty or write in a fake path it goes again and worked fine but It should have got an error but it didn't !

Can you help me out ? I don't know why the script ignores outside what I write in the path.

The reason why I need this it's simply I need for the "**to:    NASATOYMARKET.com"** part from the mails.

```
Public Sub exportNotesMail()

    Dim mailDb As Object, doc As Object, alldocs As Object, Session As Object
    Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
    Set mailDb = Session.GETDATABASE("", **"C:\Users\username\Desktop\username.nsf"**) <-- This is what is ignored outside by the script.
    If mailDb.IsOpen = False Then mailDb.OPENMAIL
    Set alldocs = mailDb.AllDocuments
    Set doc = alldocs.GetFirstDocument

    While Not (doc Is Nothing)
        'If doc.GetItemValue("Form")(0) = "Memo" Then
                x = x + 1
                Sheet2.Cells(x, 1) = doc.Created
                Sheet2.Cells(x, 2) = doc.GetItemValue("Sendto")(0)
                Sheet2.Cells(x, 3) = doc.GetItemValue("Subject")(0)
                'End If
                'Else: MsgBox "Not match"
        'End If
        Set doc = alldocs.GetNextDocument(doc)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks guys ! Yeah does the file is exist and file path it's ok and I can open with the client. So the file it's ok anyway, I followed Ken and now I get an error with this message "Type Mismatch" Here is a screenshot: http://kepfeltoltes.hu/view/140819/stof_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg Thanks for your help and time ! :)

Comment: Try it with `If mailDb.IsOpen = False Then Call mailDb.Open` (= add "Call")

Comment: I tried but it dosen't work, I don't know why but it's told me that not the good type what I want to open... but I tried to open the ".nfs" file. So I have no idea why I got this msg. :/

Might that's could be the problem --> "Dim mailDb As Object" ?

Comment: The database is not found. mailDb is Nothing. Open() is not available for Nothing. That's why you get "Type Mismatch". That's a common error message in Notes.

Comment: If the database is lokal then set GETDATABASE's first parameter to `""`

Comment: If the database is on server then you can't work with "C:\..." but have to use the path you see when you open the databases on server "LotusServer" in Notes client like "mail\TheUser.nsf".

Answer (score 1):

You have a call to OPENMAIL which will always open your personal mail file.  Change that to just OPEN and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Ken's answer. It's not **just** that you have an OPENMAIL. It's that you're using OPENMAIL as your fallback instead of doing proper error handling, then you're doing something that always causes an error, which causes your fallback to take effect.
You have to find out why the GETDATABASE call is unable to open the specified database. The way you've written it, you're trying to open a local file. Does the local file actually exist? Is it at the specified filepath? What happens if you try to open it in the client? The error message from making the attempt, will be instructive.

Answer (score 0):

Thansk Knut ! Really much !

Now that's how it works:

```
Set mailDb = NSession.GetDatabase("", "C:\Users\user\Desktop\user_rep.nsf")
If mailDb.IsOpen = False Then Call mailDb.Open
```